Controlling column order of Numpy txt output
I would like to control the print order of column data in a printout from a Numpy table.  The native savetxt function will only print in the order the _table_type was defined.  Is there a variant that will allow specifying the column order?
I know I can print the values field by field if I need to.  I'm looking for something easier.
Thanks

savetxt writes each row of the array, formatted with the fmt parameter.  Reorder/index the columns of the array before passing it to savetxt if you want something different.  savetxt is a simple writer.  Give more details if this info isn't enough.

If you have this array:
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
print(arr)

[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]

Then you can do for example:
import sys
import numpy as np

np.savetxt(sys.stdout, arr[:, [2, 0, 1]], fmt="%.2f")

Prints:
3.00 1.00 2.00
3.00 1.00 2.00
3.00 1.00 2.00


I don't know if this will work with labeled columns like I use, but I'll try it at my first opportunity.
